# How to change time format from 12h to 24h in SQL

Tags: sql, datetime, type-conversion

I have a column with a date-time format:

```
4/2/2013 4:08:00 PM
```

that I wish to change to

```
4/2/2013 16:08:00
```

I have the query where I parse it by a semi colon without the date:

```
UPDATE Datsta SET SCHED_OUT_NEW = TimeSerial(Left(SCHED_OUT,2), right(SCHED_OUT,2), 0);
```

but when I combined two fields, the date and time, **MS Access** automatically converts it back to regular time. How would I change it?

Comment: Your question says MS Access, but is tagged [tag:mysql].  They are two completely different pieces of software.  Access is a proprietary, serverless database program from Microsoft (part of their "Office" productivity suite); whilst MySQL is a free, open-source RDBMS that is now owned by Oracle.  Which do you mean?

Comment: SQL, but I figure it out, so it's fine, thanks!